# getting javax.el.ELException in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am not able to display the value in drop down. I am getting the below error when I try to display the newbFileNetStatus in drop down.

Error:

```
 javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert G of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long
```

JSP page:

```
[smm [newbID=4, planID=174, applID=18, taxqID=1, newbPolicyNo=551732891, newbEffectiveDate=null, newbIssueDate=null, newbDeliveryEMail=Admin@***.com, newbCreatedBy=C983990, newbFormsComment=document bharathi msss, newbFileNetStatus=D]]



   <div class="formcontent">
<form method="post" action="update">

    <c:forEach items="${filenetStatus}" var="filenetStatus">
        <input type="hidden" name="newbID" value="${filenetStatus.newbID}" />
        <div class="testimonials">
            <div class="left">
                <label>Plan ID</label>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input name="planID" type="text" value="${filenetStatus.planID}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonials">
            <div class="left">
                <label>New Policy Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input name="newbPolicyNo" readonly="readonly" type="text"
                    value="${filenetStatus.newbPolicyNo}" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="testimonials">
            <div class="left">
                <label>New Form Comment</label>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input name="newbFormsComment" type="text"
                    value="${filenetStatus.newbFormsComment}" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="testimonials">
            <div class="left">
                <label>Created By</label>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input name="newbCreatedBy" readonly="readonly" type="text"
                    value="${filenetStatus.newbCreatedBy}" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="testimonials">
            <div class="left">
                <label>Delivery Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input name="newbDeliveryEMail" type="text"
                    value="${filenetStatus.newbDeliveryEMail}" />
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="testimonials">
            <div class="left">
                <label>Delivery Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="right">


                <select class="dropmenu"
            name="newbFileNetStatus">


                 <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${filenetStatus.newbFileNetStatus =='G'}">
                        <option value="D">D</option>
                        <option value="C">C</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="S">S</option>
                        <option value="R">R</option>
                        <option value="${filenetStatus.newbFileNetStatus}" selected>G</option>

                    </c:when>
                    </c:choose>





        </select>
            </div>
        </div> -
```

Comment: How does the bean class for `filenetStatus` look like? And what does its `getNewbFileNetStatus()` method return - `String` or `Long`?

Comment: What is the type of `filenetStatus.newbFileNetStatus` ? Maybe it is a Long you are comparing to a String (`'G'`)

Comment: In bean class it is char public char getNewbFileNetStatus() { return newbFileNetStatus}

Comment: I need to compare it with filestatus value to display it in the drop down

Comment: I got the answer. It should be <c:when test="${filenetStatus.newbFileNetStatus eq 'G'.charAt(0) }">